# trying to run runLTspice on matlab on mac but function was written for windows

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, compatibility

I am trying to use [David Dorran's code for running `ltspice` in matlab using the function `runltspice`](https://dadorran.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/runltspice-demo/). I have run into trouble as I am using a Mac and the code was written for Windows. The trouble arises when the code looks for `scad3.exe` which doesn't exist in the files included in the Mac version of `ltspice`. Is there a different file I can search for? Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: add link to `runltspice`, and relevant tags. fix dorran's name.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Figure out the correct command for ltspice on a mac (natively). I don't have a mac so I can't help with this.

2) Use macports to run the windows version on your mac.

```
sudo port install wine
wine LTspiceIV.exe
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/LTC/LTspiceIV/scad3.exe
```

Then revise Dan's configuration script to look for & run scad3.exe in this new location and with wine.

Sources:

- http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece391/install_ltspice
- http://blog.bolkin.net/2013/07/running-ltspice-iv-on-osx.html